# Links aren't clickable. Anchors not working

Tags: css, hyperlink, anchor, social-networking

I have anchor links on icons for social media at the top of my page. As far as I can tell, the links and anchors are coded correctly.

But for some reason, I can't get the icons to be clickable.

The website is www.cleantelligent.com

Here's the code for the icons themselves:

```
<!--SOCIAL LINKS-->
<style>
#UpperLinks{ position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: 380px; white-space: nowrap;     padding-top: 27px;}
#UpperLinks img{ width:auto;}
#PhoneTop{ font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif; color:#D1D1D1; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: 345px; white-space: nowrap; margin-top: -12px;}
</style>
<div id="PhoneTop">
<img style="position:relative; top: 8px;" src="/wp-content/themes/cleantelligent/images/phonetrans.png" />(801) 375-0375</div>
<div id="UpperLinks">
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/cleantelligent_software" target="_blank" >
<img height="22" width="22" src="/wp-content/themes/cleantelligent/images/linkedin.png" /></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/CleanTelligent1" target="_blank" >
<img height="22" width="22" src="/wp-content/themes/cleantelligent/images/twitter.png" /></a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/CleanTelligent" target="_blank" >
<img height="22" width="22" src="/wp-content/themes/cleantelligent/images/facebook.png" /></a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/CTsoftware" target="_blank" >
<img class="socialicons" height="22" width="22" src="/wp-content/themes/cleantelligent/images/YouTubePlay.png" /></a>
 </div>


<!--END OF SOCIAL LINKS-->
```

Comment: i just tried it and the linked worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set your "UpperLinks" to a z-index higher than 5 or remove this z-index.  It's covering your links.

```
<div class="slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 5; ............
</div></div>
```

EDIT:
your whole page has too many z-index's going above it.  You should be able to just set that div=UpperLinks to have a z-index: 30.

Comment: Oh my goodness. Isn't it funny how there's often such a simple answer that you should have thought of? Sigh.. Thank you a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You problem is not in the snippet you have posted. You have created a `<div>` with id of `slider-1` that covers the links you have created. The part that covrs your links is transparent, so it's not obvious. With the links covered by another `<div>` you won't be ble to click them.

Try giving the links a `z-index` greater then the `<div>` that covers them.